# Chrome fails on jquery form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, forms, google-chrome

Can someone explain to me why [the form validation fails in chrome](http://demo.redaxscript.com/testformvalidation)?

Pressing the submit should colour empty fields red.

I have no idea why chrome fails - would be glad to find a solution...

```
$('form .meet').focus(function() {
    $('form .required').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).addClass('warning');
        }
    })
});
$('form .meet').click(function() {
    output = true;
    if($('form .warning').length > 0) {
        $(this).addClass('disabled').attr('disabled','disabled');
        output = false;
    }
    return output;
});
$('form .required').keyup(function() {
    if($(this).val()) {
        $(this).removeClass('warning');
        if($('form .warning').length == 0) {
            $('form .meet').removeClass('disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }
});
```

- `.required` are the input field that may not be empty
- `.meet` are the submit fields related to .required

Comment: does not look too bad, what is failing in chrome?

Comment: enter nothing and press submit - .warning class gets added in mozilla, opera and ie - but chrome fails!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome, the click event fires before focus. Your code expects the focus event to occur first (to assign warning class to empty inputs). You should perform the input field value assessment on click.

```
$('form .meet').click(function() {
    output = true;
    $('form .required').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).addClass('warning');
        }
    });
    if($('form .warning').length > 0) {
        $(this).addClass('disabled').attr('disabled','disabled');
        output = false;
    }
    return output;
});
```

Comment: That's what this is all about - helping and learning. I did not know this. Took me a while poking about with some tools to figure it out and in doing so learnt something myself. "Everyone's a winner" :)